# Add rows with increased and decreased value in groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have an example df:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'), 
                     B = c(2, 5, 8, 12, 15, 18)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

  A  B
1 A  2
2 B  5
3 C  8
4 D 12
5 E 15
6 F 18
```

I'd like to add rows with with value `B` increased and decreased by 1 in groups like this:

```
   A         B
 1 A         1
 2 A         2
 3 A         3
 4 B         4
 5 B         5
 6 B         6
 7 C         7
 8 C         8
 9 C         9
10 D        11
11 D        12
12 D        13
13 E        14
14 E        15
15 E        16
16 F        17
17 F        18
18 F        19
```

So I did something like this and it does the trick:

```
df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  complete(B = B + c(-1,1)) %>%
  arrange(B)
```

However my real data has... let's say duplicated groups:

```
df <- structure(list(A = c('A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'), 
                     B = c(2, 5, 8, 12, 15, 18)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
  A  B
1 A  2
2 A  5
3 C  8
4 D 12
5 E 15
6 F 18
```

And I still want to add 1 and `-1` to each element in group leaving the original one and keeping the order in group:

```
A         B
1 A         1
2 A         2
3 A         3
4 A         4
5 A         5
6 A         6
7 C         7
8 C         8
9 C         9
10 D        11
11 D        12
12 D        13
13 E        14
14 E        15
15 E        16
16 F        17
17 F        18
18 F        19
```

My solution doesn't work no more giving:

```
   A         B
 1 A         1
 2 A         2
 3 A         5
 4 A         6
 5 C         7
 6 C         8
(...)
```

Could you please show me how can I modify my somple `dplyr` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unnest` like below

```
df %>%
    mutate(B = list(B + (-1:1)), .by = A) %>%
    unnest(B)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 18 × 2
   A         B
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 A         1
 2 A         2
 3 A         3
 4 B         4
 5 B         5
 6 B         6
 7 C         7
 8 C         8
 9 C         9
10 D        11
11 D        12
12 D        13
13 E        14
14 E        15
15 E        16
16 F        17
17 F        18
18 F        19
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I got it:

```
df %>%
  mutate(B_plus_one = B + 1,
         B_minus_one = B - 1) %>%
  bind_rows(., mutate(., B = B_plus_one)) %>%
  bind_rows(., mutate(., B = B_minus_one)) %>%
  select(-B_plus_one, -B_minus_one) %>%
  arrange(B) %>%
  unique()

   A  B
1  A  1
3  A  2
4  A  3
5  A  4
7  A  5
8  A  6
9  C  7
11 C  8
12 C  9
13 D 11
15 D 12
16 D 13
17 E 14
19 E 15
20 E 16
21 F 17
23 F 18
24 F 19
```

Answer (score 2):

I would offer the following tidyverse solution:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(B = list(c(B - 1, B, B + 1))) %>% # or mutate(B = list(B + (-1:1))) %>% 
  unnest_longer(B)

# A tibble: 18 × 2
   A         B
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 A         1
 2 A         2
 3 A         3
 4 B         4
 5 B         5
 6 B         6
 7 C         7
 8 C         8
 9 C         9
10 D        11
11 D        12
12 D        13
13 E        14
14 E        15
15 E        16
16 F        17
17 F        18
18 F        19
```

Answer (score 2):

Using R vector [recycling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-recycling-in-r/):

```
df |> 
  slice(rep(seq_len(n()), each = 3L)) |> 
  mutate(B = B + -1L:1L)

#    A  B
# 1  A  1
# 2  A  2
# 3  A  3
# 4  B  4
# 5  B  5
# 6  B  6
# 7  C  7
# 8  C  8
# 9  C  9
# 10 D 11
# 11 D 12
# 12 D 13
# 13 E 14
# 14 E 15
# 15 E 16
# 16 F 17
# 17 F 18
# 18 F 19
```